# iOS11 Swift 4 - how to check if Swift class conforms to protocol defined in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swift4, protocols, ios11

I have a legacy code base with code written in Objective-C. I'm adding a new class written in Swift which has to conform to existing protocols defined in Objective-C.

How can I make sure my Swift class correctly implements methods defined in Objective-C protocol?

```
//In Obj-C
    @protocol OBJCLocationObserver <NSObject>
    - (void)didUpdateLocationWithModel:(nullable Model *)locationModel
                       lastLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)lastLocation;
    @end


//In Swift

    extension SwiftLocationManager : OBJCLocationObserver
    {
        public func didUpdateLocation(with model: Model?, lastLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    // How to verify this function signature is actually conforming to the Obj-C protocol and is not a new method?
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[MyClass conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];
```

According to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418893-conformstoprotocol?language=objc) you can use `conformsToProtocol:`which  returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver conforms to a given protocol.

---

**Example**

```
@protocol MyProtocol
- (void)helloWorld;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject <MyProtocol>
@end
```

Will be exposed as:

```
console.log(MyClass.conformsToProtocol(MyProtocol)); 

var instance = MyClass.alloc().init();
console.log(instance.conformsToProtocol(MyProtocol))
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you `#import` your protocol definition file into the `<ProjectName>-Bridging-Header.h` file:

```
#import "OBJCLocationObserver.h"
```

And then you should see error messages if your signature does not match.

You can also use Xcode *Auto Completion*.  Type:

```
public func didUpdateLocation
```

and *Auto Complete* suggests:

```
public func didUpdateLocation(withModel Model?, lastLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D)
```

which is different than what you have and explains why it isn't working.

---

Here is another way to get the interface:

As @MartinR suggested on a comment to another question:

> Go to the header file where the protocol is defined, and choose
>   "Generated Interface" from the "Related Items" popup in the top-left
>   corner. That will show you the exact Swift method signature that you
>   have to implement.